# I get an error when running bower install

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, bower, osx-yosemite

I just loaded a yeoman generator ( angular-fullstack ) and I get an error every time I try to run bower install. I cleared my npm cache as well as bower and I cannot find any solution as to what my issue is.

Bower version - 1.6.5
npm version - 3.3.12
node version - 4.2.2
OSX - 10.10.5

I updated my node, npm and bower but I still get this error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So Looks like I answered my own issue...Sort of. I looked around StackOverflow and the github error forums regarding this issue and a npm install issue while using the yeoman generator

The first solution was to change the code in my package.json file 
for the grunt-node-inspector

```
  "grunt-node-inspector": "~0.1.5"
```

to

```
  "grunt-node-inspector": ">=0.1.5"
```

Then I proceeded to run a npm install and that worked. After this I ran

```
npm install -g bower
```

to get the latest version of bower and since npm was working again it downloaded it fine. 
Lastly I ran a

```
bower install
```

and it loaded all my dependencies which did the trick.

I still dont know what the issue was in the first place so at best this is a work around. 
Hope it helps anyone out.